# JQuery File Upload Custom Path Problems

Tags: php, image-uploading, jquery-file-upload

I am using JQuery File Upload plugin to make add the possibility to upload files to my website.

The upload script is in a page like "index.php?cartella_id=x" (x is a number that indicated a album ID).

I would like to store files like this:

```
server/php/files
- directory 1/
- - Image x
- - Image y
- directory 2/
- - Image z
- - Image z(2)
```

I basically want to create a different directory for each album.

Storing the images like I want is not hard because I pass $cartella_id by using a hidden input in the form like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="cartella_id" value="<?php echo $cartella_id; ?>">
```

In the server/php/index.php file I check if the user is logged in and if the album exists like this

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
    die();
    }


if(isset($_REQUEST["cartella_id"])) {
    $cartella_id = (int) $_REQUEST["cartella_id"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cartelle WHERE cartella_id = $cartella_id";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if($cartella = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $upload_dir = '/files/'.$cartella_id.'/';
        } else {
        die();
        }
} else {
    die();
}
```

And in the UploadHandler.php page I edit the 'upload_dir' and 'upload_url' options.

```
'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/'.$_REQUEST["cartella_id"].'/',
            'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/'.$_REQUEST["cartella_id"].'/',
```

Upload works fine... the problem is that if I refresh the upload page I can't see already-uploaded files like the script would show me when no custom path is specified. I can use $_SESSION to fix this problem but I don't like this solution and the Delete buttons wouldn't work in any case.

I studied the PHP code a lot and I've also googled a lot but I couldn't find a solution that works for me.

How do I send custom variables when the script is checking for existing files (I couldn't find that piece of code)?
How do I make the Delete buttons work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved the first problem (make files visible even after reloading the page) by editing js/main.js.
I edited this:

```
url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
```

to this

```
url: ($('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url') + "?cartella_id="+ document.getElementById('cartella_id').value),
```

Still have to make the delete buttons work though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it enabling the user-directories and overriding the methods in the class UploadHandler as suggested here:

[jQuery-File-Upload PHP-user-directories](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-user-directories)

I added an extra parameter to the delete url.

My index.php :

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

require('UploadHandler.php');

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {

    protected function get_user_id() {
        return $_REQUEST['recordId'];
    }

    protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
        $file->deleteUrl = $this->options['script_url']
            .$this->get_query_separator($this->options['script_url'])
            .$this->get_singular_param_name()
            .'='.rawurlencode($file->name)
            .'&recordId='.$_REQUEST['recordId']
            ;
        $file->deleteType = $this->options['delete_type'];
        if ($file->deleteType !== 'DELETE') {
            $file->deleteUrl .= '&_method=DELETE';
        }
        if ($this->options['access_control_allow_credentials']) {
            $file->deleteWithCredentials = true;
        }
    }   

}

$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler(array(
    'user_dirs' => true,
));
```

and i changed the url in

my main.js:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: 'server/php/index.php?recordId=' + recordId,
    });

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );

        // Load existing files:
        $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
        $.ajax({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $('#fileupload')[0]
        }).always(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        }).done(function (result) {
            $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
        });

});

}
```

i have not edited the UploadHandler.php